# Where do I see a log of user connections to PC in Windows Server 2008 Event Log Viewer?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, audit

Event Log Viewer is listing a bunch of infos but where am I supposed to see the list of user connections to PC in Windows Server 2008 ?

Answer (score 0):

The Security event log will have all the requests to authenticate.  If you enable auditing there will be a bunch more information.